# Is it normal for `ldd --version` to exit 1?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I'm on a musl-based OS (my first) and `ldd --version` prints to standard error:

```
musl libc (x86_64)
Version 1.1.15
Dynamic Program Loader
Usage: ldd [options] [--] pathname
```

And it exits with `1` status. This also happens for `ldd --help`. Is this normal for `ldd --version`?

Comment: You're [not the only one](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/564#issuecomment-259461839) (unless it's your comment).

Comment: It returns 0 for me on both cases, but what the heck is that system?

Comment: @JuliePelletier It's Void Linux w/ musl instead of glibc: https://www.reddit.com/r/voidlinux/comments/3h8aug/difference_between_musl_and_nonmusl_isos/   I wanted to try it out since it seemed lighter-weight. But, I knew the downsides: A lot of software assumes a Linux distro uses glibc. So some software is much more difficult to obtain and compile. OpenJDK is not even available at the moment. (Not that I ever use Java.)

Comment: @techraf Thanks. That answered my question. How did you find  that page?

Comment: @techraf I meant, "What were the keywords?"  I used Google Search too, but couldn't find it.

Comment: @dgo.a included in the answer; I tried to find source, but unsuccessfully

Comment: @techraf Thanks. I also see what I was doing wrong with my Google search: I forgot to put the version in the keywords and limiting the search to the last year.  Dumb mistake on my part. Sorry.

Comment: musl 1.1.15 was released this year, so version number would be enough, no need to limit the published date ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this normal for `ldd --version`?

While other versions give return code 0, Google Search (for `+"Version 1.1.15" +"Dynamic Program Loader"`) revealed that [there are reports](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/564#issuecomment-259461839) of the version you use (1.1.15) behaving this way (and causing problems):

> ```
> db02d024bb15:~# ldd --version 2>&1
> musl libc (x86_64)
> Version 1.1.15
> Dynamic Program Loader
> Usage: ldd [options] [--] pathname
> db02d024bb15:~# echo $?
> 1
> ```